# System.Type property to T Type parameter

Tags: vb.net, types, parameters, properties

Good day everyone

I have a Type in a property that I would like to use into a function that asks for a T parameter:

```
Sub DoStuff(Of T)()
    'DoStuff   '
End Sub

Dim info() as PropertyInfo = source.GetType.GetProperties()
For Each itm In info
  If itm.PropertyType Is GetType(String) Or itm.PropertyType Is GetType(Decimal) Then
      DoStuff(Of itm.PropertyType)()
  End If
Next
```

How can I pass the PropertyType as parameter for a T type?, I have quite a lot of types involved so it'll be a dirty code if I specify each one.

I've searched a lot but cannot find some solution, maybe it's the way I'm searching, not sure how to differ type of PropertyType from T type.